# How to update a whole column with complete new data

Tags: sql-update, oracle-sqldeveloper

So i am trying to create an update call, where i exchange all the data in my column with new data i generated.
For e.g.

```
column1 column2 
1       A
2       B
3       C
4       D
```

and the new data for column1 would 5,6,7,8

so that it would display

```
column1 column2
5       A
6       B
7       C
8       D
```

Comment: is the data you presented real data? If yes, do it as follow : Update table-name set column1 = column1+4

Comment: It isnt the real data, in real i would exchange different hash values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using PL/SQL FOR-LOOP and go through all rows in the table one by one, updating column1.

You can read more here:
[Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems053.htm)